# table cell input returns as undefined

Tags: jquery, jquery-2.0

I am using `jquery 2` 
I need to populate a multidimensional array with values in a table

Here is my code (First column is hidden)

html:

```
<table  id="datatab"  border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr role="row" class="odd">
            <td class="sorting_1" style="display: none;">2087971</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>John Smith</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value1" value="1"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value2" value="2"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value3" value="3"></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
        <tr role="row" class="even">
            <td class="sorting_1" style="display: none;">2087972</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>bbbb</td>
            <td>Peter Parker</td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value1" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value2" value="4"></td>
            <td><input type="text"  name="value3" value="4"></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="GetData">Get data</button>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#GetData").click(function (event) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();
        var TableData = new Array();
        $('#datatab tbody tr').each(function (row, tr) {
            TableData[row] = {
                "id": $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
                , "value1": $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').find("input").value
                , "value2": $(tr).find('td:eq(6)').find("input").value
                , "value3": $(tr).find('td:eq(7)').find("input").value
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

I populate the first id column successfully in my array with the line

```
$(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text()
```

However the values of the inputs are `undefined`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `val()` method of the jQuery objects, as they do not have `value` property like the underlying DOMElements. Also note that you can use `map()` to build the array. Try this:

```
$("#GetData").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var tableData = $('#datatab tbody tr').map(function(row, tr) {
        var $row = $(tr);
        return {
            id: $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            value1: $row.find('td:eq(5) input').val(), 
            value2: $row.find('td:eq(6) input').val(),
            value3: $row.find('td:eq(7) input').val()
        }
    }).get();

    // work with tableData here...
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/n84pfL6r/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help